# How to check for a specific string in a small text file

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How would it be possible to find out if a string for example "testing" is within a text file or not?

Comment: Not sure about the exact C# code but I guess  you can scan the file in a linear fashion using a while loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Description

Assuming your Text File is not too big you can use this function

#### Sample

```
public static bool IsStringInFile(string fileName, string searchString)
{
    return File.ReadAllText(fileName).Contains(searchString);
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - File.ReadAllLines Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx)
- [MSDN - String.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

Comment: Nothing ;) I extend my answer. Thank you! I upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The naïve approach:

```
var result = File.ReadAllText("path to file").Contains("string to search for");
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is reasonably small, you can just read it into a string and look for the string inside it:

```
if (File.ReadAllText(fileName).Contains("testing")) {
  // the string was in there
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
if (readText.Contains("testing"))
  //found text in file
```